# preselect the drop down value based on the value from another column

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a table that has drop down inside it. The drop down has values like this :

```
This is Test1
This is Test2
This is Test3
This is Test4
This is Test5
```

There is another row in the table that says Test1 or Test2 and so on. Please see below image:

[image]

in the above table, if the first column says "Test1", I want the drop down to pre select "This is test1". If the first column says "Test3"
then I want the drop down to select the text "This is Test3".

below is my controller code:

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
   {
        
        ViewData["DocumentType"] = new SelectList(docTypes, "Id", "Description");
   }
```

description is basically this:

```
This is Test1
This is Test2
This is Test3
This is Test4
This is Test5
```

this is my view

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            
                            <th>FileName</th>
                            <th>Type</th>
                            <th>Record Date</th>
                         
                        </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody>
                  @if (Model != null)
                        {
                            @foreach (var item in Model)
                            {
                            <tr>
                              <td>
                               <td>
                                        <label id="lblName_@item.DocumentId">@item.Name</label>
                                   
                              </td>
                              <td>
                              <select class="form-control" style="min-width:150px" id="ddldoc_@item.DocumentId" asp-for="@item.DocumentType" asp-items="ViewBag.DocumentType"></select>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            }
                        }
                 
                 
                 </tbody>

         How can I select the value of the drop down based on the first column value.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the default value when creating new SelectList in cshtml. Try this sample:
Items.cs

```
    public class Item
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }    
        public string DocumentId { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller

```
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.options = new List<string>() {
                "This is Test1",
                "This is Test2",
                "This is Test3",
                "This is Test4",
                "This is Test5"
            };

            var model = new List<Item>()
            {
                new Item {Name="Test1"},
                new Item {Name="Test3"},
                new Item {Name="Test2"},
                new Item {Name="Test5"},
            };
            return View(model);
        }
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model List<Item>

<table>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            string selected = String.Empty;
            foreach (var option in ViewBag.options)
            {
                if (option.Contains(item.Name))
                {
                    selected = option;
                }
            };
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>@item.Name</label>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <select asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.options,selected))" asp-for="@item.DocumentId"></select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Result
[image]